# Select polygons that intersect points in QGIS using WFS data

Tags: qgis, sql, wfs, query, intersect

How to select polygons that intersect points in QGIS using WFS data? I am trying to select polygons from a WFS remote database that intersect a local point shapefile. The selection by location does not work with distant data.
Is there a SQL equivalence for intersect?

Comment: Is it an option to download the WFS layer locally?

Comment: No the file is too heavy